# OSX versions with pthread_barrier

Tags: c, macos, pthreads, posix, pthread-barriers

Some years ago I wrote some open-source C using POSIX thread barriers, a user on OSX reported a compile failure since these were not implemented on their OS, so we collaborated and ported a primitive implementation into the code, they could then compile and run the code multithreaded.

I have occasion to to do the same thing again, on searching on the obvious terms (`posix barrier osx missing` and the like) I find that hits tend to be earlier than 2015.  So my question:  Do recent verisons of OSX support barriers? If so, what's the first version that did so?

Comment: Your question is a good one.  It's likely to get more attention with an appropriate language tag.  I've added "C" based on the question text, but if you happen to actually be using C++ instead then do switch the tag.  (But in that case, be aware that you can expect recommendations to use `std::thread` and friends instead of calling pthreads functions.)

Comment: Instead of searching specifically for information about pthreads barrier support being *missing* on macOS, I searched more generally, using terms "macos thread barrier".  I got no hits about Mac providing pthreads barriers natively, but I got some pretty recent ones about working around their absence.  This is not conclusive, but it does suggest that macOS still does not provide pthread barriers.